# Kubernetes HTTP Traffic goes to pod being updated

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

I'm having a pipeline that has the following structure:

```sh
Step 1: kubernetes-deployment
Step 2: kubectl rollout restart deploy -n NAMESPACE
Step 3: http-calls to deployment A and B
```

In the same Namespace, there's a database pod and Pod **A** and **B** are connected to this database.

## The problem

The problem now is caused by rolling updates - when applying a rolling update, kubernetes starts new pods as the deployment got updated. The old pod is not terminated until the corresponding new pod starts, though.

As `kubectl rollout restart deploy` is a non-blocking call, it will not wait for the update to finish. And afaik, there is no builtin way of kubectl to force such behavior.

As I'm executing some HTTP Requests after this was called, i now got the problem that **sometimes**, when the update is not fast enough, the HTTP Calls are received and answered by the old pods from deployment **A** and **B**. Shortly after this, the old pods will be terminated, as the new ones are up and running.

This leads to the problem that the effects of those HTTP requests are no longer visible, as they were received by the old pods, saving the corresponding data in a database located in the "old" database pod. As database pod is restarted, the data will be lost.

Note that I am not using a `persistent Volume` in this case, as this comes from a nightly build scenario and i want to restart those deployments every day and the database state should always contain only the data from the current day's build.

Do you see any way of solving this?
Including a simple `wait` step would probably work, but I am curious if there is a fancier solution.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Configure a readiness probe on your pods. Configuring a liveness probe if not already there is also a good practice.

Comment: I've not used a readiness / liveness probe yet, but would'nt this lead to the same situation, if the HTTP calls are executed too early? Or is there a functionality of k8s to not send traffic to deployment pods that are being updated, if there is a readiness probe configured?

Comment: When the pod starts, no traffic is routed to it until the readiness probe says "ok".

Comment: Yes, but lets say i have deployment A with readiness probe running (and it says OK), then i'm updating deployments and then im executing my HTTP requests ("new" pod of deployment A was not created yet by k8s or is not running yet). In this scenario, to my understanding, the old pod still will receive the HTTP traffic and the "new" one won't. Or am i wrong?

Comment: You are not wrong, unless you set the deployment strategy to Recreate, which will first scale down Pod A, then will scale back up Pod B. The problem at this point could be that no one can answer your requests until B is ready to accept them. You could poll the Pod status in your script to wait until the Pod itself declares it is now Ready (which will be only when the readiness probe will be OK)

Comment: Maybe the [blue/green deployment](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/continuous-blue-green-deployments-with-kubernetes) is what you need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kubectl rollout status deployment <deploymentname>` together with `startupProbe` and `livenessProbe` solved my problem.